# JavaMail - Java application doesn't receive folder events

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am developing a java application which listens and receives IMAP folder events, however, I couldn't get the following code working. Clearly, I am missing an important method call or configuration. What should I do to get Folder events?

```
    IMAPSSLStore store = (IMAPSSLStore)session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect("host","username","pwd");
    store.addFolderListener(new FolderListener() {
            @Override
            public void folderCreated(FolderEvent fe) {
                //do something
            }

            @Override
            public void folderDeleted(FolderEvent fe) {
                //do something
            }

            @Override
            public void folderRenamed(FolderEvent fe) {
                //do something
            }
        });

        for(;;) {
            store.idle();
        }
```

I tried adding the listener to a Folder as well modifiying the sample code. I am using a standard email client to test folder creation and deletion. However, events are not delivered to my java app. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the IMAP protocol doesn't provide notifications for these events, so JavaMail can only notify you of these events if another thread in your application using the same Store performs one of these operations.

Comment: It is interesting. Does this also apply to POP3Folder and/or GmailFolder?

Comment: Yes, it's a limitation of the protocols being used.